# Double nested_attributes with uniqueness

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes, has-many

Here is 3 sample classes in Rails 4.1.4. `B` can be seen as an `has_and_belongs_to_many` middle class (but it's not):

```
class A < AR::Base
  has_many :bs
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :bs
end

class B < AR::Base
  belongs_to :c
  belongs_to :a
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :c
end

class C < AR::Base
  has_many :bs
end
```

This structure allows me to create objets like this :

```
a = A.create!({
  :attr_a => 'valA',
  :b_attributes => {
    0 => {
      :attr_b => 'valB0',
      :c_attributes => { :attr_c => 'valC' }
    },
    1 => {
      :attr_b => 'valB1',
      :c_attributes => { :attr_c => 'valC' }
    }
  }
})
```

It works perfecly, I have an object A, 2 objects B and 2 objects C.

The problem is that I want to **add a unicity of C's attr_c**. So I add this line in `C` model :

```
validates :attr_c, :uniqueness => true
```

But... No problem for Rails, the **2 instances of `C` are created**, with exactly the same name. I point out that when I want to create 2 instance of `C` "manually" (without nested_attributes), it raise the correct error.

Is there any method to :

- raise this error ?

or

- automatically set the same `c` instance for the 2 `b` in the saving process ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that C object is build but not persisted, are you sure?, what about adding `validates :c, associated: true` to B class?

Comment: @MichalSzyndel I'm totally sure that 2 C objects are created (in database, with different ids). Your solution with associated validations doesn't resolve the issue.

Comment: Ok, what about trying to add `autosave: true` to associations, and validation everywhere? BTW why don't you use HABTM?